# Produce custom content using Mongoosejs, login-based application?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

The application is developed using Express.js & MongoDB. The application would have users logged-in, a session would be maintained. It is a billing application.

There are five models: 
* User, 
 
* Invoice, 
 
* Payment, 
* Client, 
* Product. 
Each other than the User has "ref" programmed as >> userID: req.user._id.

When the user logs in, with the user's ID all the data related to invoices, payments, clients & products is getting stored, to produce uniqueness.

The system is working perfectly fine until the above-explained flow.

**Now, the problem statement...**

"The application should render custom invoices, payments, clients and products as the user logs in & obviously with respect to the user, but this is not happening"

**How I structured the application?**

I have used "mongoose.js" to deal with MongoDB. Each model above represents a collection associated. When rendering either of the invoices, payments, clients or products, a ".populate(user)" is also coded.

Following is the User Model:

```
// User Model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Following is the Invoice Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

// Create Schema
const InvoiceSchema = new Schema({
    inv_no: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true
    },
    c_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    item_code: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    item_desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    qty: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = Invoice = mongoose.model('invoices', InvoiceSchema);
```

Following is the example route for user population:

```
Invoice.get('/invoices', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}),  (req, res) => {
    if(req.session && req.cookies) {
        res.append('Authorization', req.cookies.jwt);

        /* Find Data */

        // Invoice Collection Block 
        Invoice.
            find()
            .populate('users', 'username')
            .then(invoiceData => {
                let inv_number;
                if(invoiceData.length >= 1) {
                    inv_number = invoiceData.slice(-1)[0].inv_no;
                    inv_number = inv_number + 1;
                }
                else if(invoiceData.length === 0) {
                    inv_number = 1;
                }

                // Clients Collection Block
                Client
                    .find()
                    .then(clientData => {

                        // Products Collection Block
                        Product
                            .find()
                            .then(productData => {

                                if(clientData && productData) {
                                    // Rendering Block   
                                    res.render('invoices', {
                                        user: req.user.name,
                                        sno: inv_number,
                                        client: clientData,
                                        items: productData
                                    });  
                                }
                                else {
                                    // Rendering Block   
                                    res.render('invoices', {
                                        user: req.user.name,
                                        sno: inv_number,
                                        client: null,
                                        items: null
                                    });
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(errPrd => console.log(errPrd));
                    })
                    .catch(errClt => console.log(errClt));;
            })
            .catch(errInv => console.log(errInv));
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your invoice schema userId is referred to users.

```
    Invoice.
        find()
        .populate('userId', 'username')
```